# Files not showing up on MinIO console

Tags: docker-compose, minio

I am running two Docker containers from the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - ~/minio/data:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_CLIENT_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY}
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    restart: unless-stopped

  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc:latest
    entrypoint: sh
    depends_on:
      - minio
    volumes:
      - ~/minio/data:/data
    command: -c "mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 ${MINIO_CLIENT_ACCESS_KEY} ${MINIO_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY} && mc mb myminio/${MINIO_BUCKET_NAME} && mc anonymous set public myminio/${MINIO_BUCKET_NAME} && mc mirror --watch /data/${MINIO_BUCKET_NAME} myminio/${MINIO_BUCKET_NAME} && tail -f /dev/null"
```

I created a test folder in ~/minio/data/${MINIO_BUCKET_NAME} on my host machine and a test.txt file within the test folder.

When I open the MinIO console, I can see the test folder but not the test.txt file. I also entered the container to make sure that the file was present and it is.

Do you guys have any ideas why?

Thank you

Comment: Minio isn't a file server. You should use `mc cp` or minio's API to upload files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade MinIO to an older version released prior to 2022-06-02 to restore this functionality. And because MinIO won't let you do a downgrade either (presumably to prevent you from performing unwanted actions like restoring the file system serving functionality), you will also need to remove their metadata folder `.minio.sys` before MinIO starts working as a file server for existing files once again (beware of vulnerabilities in such old containers though).

*Explanation*

Unfortunately for those maintaining these systems, Minio team has decided to deprecate access to existing files (see [this discussion](https://github.com/minio/minio/discussions/15496)). They will continue working for existing setups (where access to the file system was first made possible under older MinIO versions), but when you start MinIO on a new data folder, and a new MinIO metadata folder `.minio.sys` is created, it won't see any existing files (until you vendor-lock them by passing through the MinIO API, but beware - that in turn would make many of your files unreadable to the original applications that created these files, such as Jupyter Notebook - this applies to all that are effectively zipped file folders such as `.ipynb` or `.jar` or `.xlsx`).

---

Note also that a workaround that involved manually crafting `format.json` (described in [this Github issue](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/15633)), which used to work in some MinIO versions from late 2022 no longer works - if you tamper with `format.json` that way, MinIO console would fail to you in log, giving you an error message instead ("Corrupted backend format, specified drive mount has unexpected previous content").